# Memset() in Python, clearing buffer

Tags: python, c, pointers, memset

I trying convert some C code to Python and have problem with clearing buffer (data which will be send by UDP). Function to convert looks like:

```
void func(Struct *data_1, Struct *data_2)
{
    data_p1 = data_1;
    data_p2 = data_2;
    memset(datap1, 0, sizeof(*data_p1));
    memset(datap2, 0, sizeof(*data_p2));
}
```

And I have to problms,I don't know how to replace c pointers and is that crucial to replace them. Second problem is that memset, I know that is `ctype` but I don't know how to properly use it. Can anyone help?

Comment: This code fills (initializes) the values of the structures with zeros. I don’t think it is worthwhile to literally transfer the code to python, objects in it can be initialized in another way, for example, in the `__init__` or just assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting code between different languages, never try to convert at the expression level, but wonder what the code is actually doing. Here the C code sets the content of a struct to NULL bytes. There is no direct equivalent in Python, full stop. The closer equivalent way would be to set all object attributes of a Python object to None, set integers to 0 and floats to 0.0.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. Thank you